# dateutil not parsing my timezone correctly

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm trying to parse a string to get the datetime object. I'm using the dateutil library to parse my input string.

Tried this code

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

datetime_str = '2023-06-29T00:15:53Z'      #Z implies UTC timezone
tzinfos = {"Z": -18000}                    #I want the EST timezone which is -5. Hence, -180000
parse(datetime_str, ignoretz=False, tzinfos=tzinfos)
```

But this gives me the output-

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 29, 0, 15, 53, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

Why is it not following my timezone instructions? My tzinfos dictionary specifically maps 'Z' to an offset of -18000. But it still shows me tzlocal().

**** UPDATE ****

Okay, I think I have zeroed in on the problem. If I replace 'Z' with something like 'BRST' or 'CST', and correspondingly update the tzinfos dictionary, the tzinfos are updated successfully. So why is it giving me a problem with 'Z'. Is it because dateutil.parser doesn't like single chars timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTC timezone abbreviations are special cased in the source code (`UTC`, `GMT`, `Z`, `z`): See [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/296d419fe6bf3b22897f8f210735ac9c4e1cb796/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L288C5-L288C13) and [here](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/296d419fe6bf3b22897f8f210735ac9c4e1cb796/src/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L355)

You can subclass `parserinfo` and override `UTCZONE` if you really need to make `Z` mean something other than `UTC`, but I would probably suggest to not do that.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow. I have no problem keeping 'Z' to mean the UTC. But as per my code, the returned object shows 'tzinfo=tzlocal()'. Why is it now showing 'tzinfo=UTC' or something like that.

Comment: @FahdS I have no idea and i can't reproduce using the exact code from your question and the version that comes with `pip install dateutil`.

Comment: And FWIW, if you are ok with keeping `Z` meaning UTC, you shouldn't pass anything to `tzinfos`.

Comment: It might be that your computer is in a UTC timezone, so `tzlocal()==tzutc()`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! appreciate the help!!